# Access current user within liquid drop rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, liquid

I'm currently implementing liquid templates in my application. As part of that I have created a set of liquid drop (https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Trying-to-Understand-Drops) classes to act as intermediates between my models and my templates. I'm currently using devise for authentication on rails 5.

In my product drop class I would like to be able to check if my current user owns the product:

```
class ProductDrop < Liquid::Drop

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def owned_by_user?
     #somehow access the current_user provided by devise.
  end

end
```

But haven't been able to figure out how to access the user.

I notice in this method on shopify: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/variant#variant-selected
They are able to access the current url to work out if the variant is selected. I thought perhaps it might be possible if they can access the url, to access the session and get the user identifier to look up the user.

So I can do something like:

```
def owned_by_user?
   User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).owns_product?(@model.id)
end
```

I'm not having any luck accessing the session. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after digging around in the liquid drop source code. I noticed that the context is accessible to the drop (https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/drop.rb). I totally missed it the first time I looked.

So the solution ended up being:

First add the user so it is available to the controller action the view is rendered for. this then gets added to the context by the liquid template handler (and therefore exists in the context)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_common_variables

  def set_common_variables
    @user = current_user # Or how ever you access your currently logged in user
  end

end
```

Add the method to the product to get the user from the liquid context

```
class ProductDrop < Liquid::Drop

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def name
    @model.name
  end

  def user_owned?
    return @context['user'].does_user_own_product?(@model.id)
  end

end
```

Then add the method to the user to check if the user owns the product or not:

```
class UserDrop < Liquid::Drop

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def nick_name
    @model.nick_name
  end

  def does_user_own_product?(id)
    @model.products.exists?(id: id)
  end

end
```

Obviously this needs error handling and so on. but hopefully that helps someone. Also if anyone knows of a better way, keen to hear it.